# FG Joomla to Wordpress Plugin doesn't migrate web pages

Tags: wordpress, joomla, migration

I have been trying to migrate my website from joomla to wordpress using the FG Joomla to wordpress plugin. It only migrate post, categories and media only. Does it also import web pages e.g home, about or services page.

I have played around with the behavior settings nothing seems to work.  Anyone with ideas on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are managed by native Joomla, they will be imported by the plugin. If they are managed by a third-party plugin, you may need an add-on to import them.
You should contact the support team at https://www.fredericgilles.net/support/